# How retrieves ASN.1 encoded information from PEM encoded key in iOS

Tags: swift, encryption, private-key, asn.1

Currently using Apple CommonCrypto, to make some encryptions. We have web application that use cryptography to keep zero knowledge principle, now we want to move this approach to iOS application.
I read about [ASN.1](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/a-warm-welcome-to-asn1-and-der/), when try to parse using tool that is there I receive error -  not valid characters, but to be able to decrypt I need to remove some extra symbols. So to decrypt password, I need to pass several steps, one of it - to get salt, that is encrypted inside private key. private key looks like this:

```
"-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----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\r\ntObwa4cNvekoknk4jhXyjbySJUB6E8TJal67gkyPCE/xACYniPY=\r\n-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

I need to retrieves ASN.1 encoded information from PEM encoded key. Web developers use library that does all these decryption, and as a decrypted value they receive:

```
const res = {
    salt: this.hexStringToArrayBuffer(opt.salt),
    iv: this.hexStringToArrayBuffer(opt.iv),
    cipher: opt.cipher,
    length: opt.length,
    hash: opt.hash,
    iter: opt.iter,
    encryptedData: this.hexStringToArrayBuffer(opt.encryptedData),
  };
```

I need to use the same approach and be able decrypt these private keys. I searched a lot and haven't yet found any proper solution for swift. I will be very thankful for any advice.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for solution, I used to translate JS framework to swift and decrypted pem key:

```
    func getParsedKey(privateKey: String) -> ResultDecoded? {
    var privateKey = privateKey
    privateKey = privateKey.replacingOccurrences(of: "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----", with: "")
    privateKey = privateKey.replacingOccurrences(of: "-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----", with: "")
    privateKey = privateKey.replacingOccurrences(of: "\r\n", with: "")
    guard let data = Data(base64EncodedURLSafe: privateKey) else {
        // handle errors in decoding base64 string here
        return nil
    }
    let hex = data.hexa
    var opt = Opt()
    opt.data = hex
    if hex.contains(PBES2_OID) && hex.contains(PBKDF2_OID) {
        opt.valid = true
    }
    if let range = hex.range(of: PBKDF2_OID) {
        opt.saltBegin = hex.distance(from: hex.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound) + 28
    }
    
    if let range = opt.data.range(of: AES256GCM_OID) {
        opt.cipher = "AES-GCM"
        opt.length = 256;
        opt.ivBegin = hex.distance(from: hex.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound) + 24;
      } else if let range = opt.data.range(of: AES192GCM_OID) {
        opt.cipher = "AES-GCM"
        opt.length = 192;
        opt.ivBegin = hex.distance(from: hex.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound) + 24;
      } else if let range = opt.data.range(of: AES128GCM_OID) {
        opt.cipher = "AES-GCM";
        opt.length = 128;
        opt.ivBegin = hex.distance(from: hex.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound) + 24;
      } else if let range = opt.data.range(of: AES256CBC_OID) {
        opt.cipher = "AES-CBC";
        opt.length = 256;
        opt.ivBegin = hex.distance(from: hex.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound) + 24;
      } else if let range = opt.data.range(of: AES192CBC_OID) {
        opt.cipher = "AES-CBC";
        opt.length = 192;
        opt.ivBegin = hex.distance(from: hex.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound) + 24;
      } else if let range = opt.data.range(of: AES128CBC_OID) {
        opt.cipher = "AES-CBC";
        opt.length = 128;
        opt.ivBegin = hex.distance(from: hex.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound) + 24;
      } else if let range = opt.data.range(of: AES256CFB_OID) {
        opt.cipher = "AES-CFB";
        opt.length = 256;
        opt.ivBegin = hex.distance(from: hex.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound) + 24;
      } else if let range = opt.data.range(of: AES192CFB_OID) {
        opt.cipher = "AES-CFB";
        opt.length = 192;
        opt.ivBegin = hex.distance(from: hex.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound) + 24;
      } else if let range = opt.data.range(of: AES128CFB_OID) {
        opt.cipher = "AES-CFB";
        opt.length = 128;
        opt.ivBegin = hex.distance(from: hex.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound) + 22;
      }

    if opt.data.contains(SHA512_OID) {
      opt.hash = "SHA-512"
    } else if opt.data.contains(SHA384_OID) {
      opt.hash = "SHA-384"
    } else if opt.data.contains(SHA256_OID) {
      opt.hash = "SHA-256"
    } else if opt.data.contains(SHA1_OID) {
      opt.hash = "SHA-1"
    }
    
    opt.saltLength = opt.data.subString(from: opt.saltBegin, to: 2).integerValue()
    opt.ivLength = opt.data.subString(from: opt.ivBegin, to: 2).integerValue()
    opt.salt = opt.data.subString(from: opt.saltBegin + 2, to: opt.saltLength * 2)
    opt.iv = opt.data.subString(from: opt.ivBegin + 2, to: opt.ivLength * 2);
    
    opt.iterBegin = opt.saltBegin + 4 + opt.saltLength * 2;
    opt.iterLength = opt.data.subString(from:opt.iterBegin, to: 2).integerValue()
    opt.iter = opt.data.subString(from: opt.iterBegin + 2, to: opt.iterLength * 2).integerValue()
    
    opt.sequencePadding = opt.data.subString(from: 2, to: 2) == "81" ? 8 : 10;
    opt.parametersPadding = opt.data.subString(from: 2, to: 2) == "81" ? 12 : 16;
    opt.sequenceLength = opt.data.subString(from: opt.sequencePadding, to: 2).integerValue()
    opt.encryptedDataBegin = opt.parametersPadding + opt.sequenceLength * 2;
    opt.encryptedDataPadding =
    opt.data.subString(from: opt.encryptedDataBegin - 2, to: 2) == "81" ? 2 : 4;
    let sublength = opt.data.subString(from: opt.encryptedDataBegin, to: 6)
    opt.encryptedDataLength = sublength.integerValue()
    opt.encryptedData = opt.data.subString(from: opt.encryptedDataBegin + opt.encryptedDataPadding,
                                           to: opt.encryptedDataLength * 2)
    
    
    return ResultDecoded(salt: Data(opt.salt.utf8),
                         iv: opt.iv.hexaBytes,
                         cipher: opt.cipher,
                         length: opt.length,
                         hash: opt.hash,
                         iter: opt.iter,
                         encryptedData: opt.encryptedData.hexaBytes)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decrypt -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----

In openssl that would be

openssl rsa -in enc.key -out dec.key

if you are using rsa you would been to provide the passphrase for the encrypted key:

In you case:

1. Base64 decode the private key
2. decrypt the private key using the passphrase
3. base64 the result (or use it as the source for your ASN.1 decode

Comment: I need to do this from code, not from terminal...There is no rsa  and passphrase

Comment: If it is encrypted private key there is some algorithm whether it's RSA or something else and there is a passphrase whether it's blank or something else

Comment: but how to do this from code?